# How to force a browser to save field content for later?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-web-services

I use Chrome. On some sites it seems that it remembers an immense number of entries for different fields. I find it very handy. However, on some sites, it doesn't do so well. One example that is driving me crazy is on the AWS console. When updating a Lambda function I need to copy a file over from S3. There is a field that requires a very long URL that I have to go retrieve elsewhere every time.
[image: AWS Lambda Screenshot]

The HTML for the field is:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="on" id="awsui-textfield-5"
class="awsui-textfield awsui-textfield-type-text">
```

Because of the `autocomplete="on"` I would expect Chrome to just "do the right thing™", but maybe because the field is not in a `<form>` it's not.

### What conditions must occur in order to have a field be saved?

I frequently make bookmarklets or userscripts to solve little annoyances with websites. I would love to do that here, but I don't know what needs to change.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it for this one case! I think the solution will probably apply to many others. I made a [bookmarklet](http://richardbronosky.github.io/Perfect-Bookmarklets/save_field.html) and chunk of javascript that you can paste into a "Developer Tools" console.

```
var jq_tag=document.createElement('script');
jq_tag.setAttribute('src','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jq_tag);
setTimeout(function() {
  var tf=$(document.activeElement);
  var ff=$('<form method="post" target="_blank" action="//example.com"><input type="submit" value="Save this field data"></form>');
  tf.after(ff);
  ff.prepend(tf);
}, 2000);
```

By design (to make it more general purpose), it requires that you have your cursor in the text field in question. When you run the JS, a "Save this field data" button will appear after the field.

This is a breakdown of what it is doing line by line:

```
# Create a script tag in memory.
# Make it source jQuery.
# Attach it to do the <head> of the document which begins loading it.
# Barbaric workaround for waiting for the JS to load.
# Get the element that has focus.
# Create a form that will POST to example.com in a new tab.
# Attach the form to the DOM right after the "focused element".
# Detach the "focused element" and reattach it inside the new form element.
```

Here is it in action...
[image]